# What could cause a MySQL server to "halt"?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, memory-table

[According to MySQL's help page on MEMORY engines...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

> When the MySQL server halts or restarts, the data in MEMORY tables is lost.

I am running a MEMORY table on an Amazon ec2 t1.micro instance, and everything was going relatively fine until about an hour ago when I realized that all of my MEMORY tables were wiped.

I did not reset the server, it is still running fine, although in my logs I realized that the CPU load was getting quite high as I was pushing the server a bit too hard it seems.

The CPU system load averages were reading `4.98, 3.32, 2.22 (1,5,15)` just a few minutes before the crash.

Is it possible that the high CPU load on a single core micro instance could cause my MySQL server to "halt" and thus drop all memory tables?

Thank goodness I have a backup... I'll be restarting without pushing the server so hard this time.

I have copied my MySQL error.log file tail end below:

```
150511 21:14:39 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
150511 21:14:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150511 21:14:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150511 21:14:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150511 21:14:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150511 21:14:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150511 21:14:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150511 21:14:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150511 21:14:42 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
150511 21:14:42  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
150511 21:14:59  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150511 21:15:00 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 12053647257
150511 21:15:00 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150511 21:15:00 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150511 21:15:00 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150511 21:15:01 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150511 21:15:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
150511 21:15:17 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './phpmyadmin/pma_column_info' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150511 21:15:17 [Warning] Checking table:   './phpmyadmin/pma_column_info'
150511 21:15:18 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './phpmyadmin/pma_recent' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150511 21:15:18 [Warning] Checking table:   './phpmyadmin/pma_recent'
150511 21:15:18 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './phpmyadmin/pma_table_uiprefs' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150511 21:15:18 [Warning] Checking table:   './phpmyadmin/pma_table_uiprefs
```

This occurred right around when I was saying the CPU was going through the roof. I'm not sure what it all means yet, but I'm assuming the mysql server reset here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't think of `3.77` as high enough to crash/freeze your server.  Look to the error logs of the mysqld.

Comment: It hit 4.98 actually, I have edited the post to reflect that. Would you think 4.98 to be high enough to halt the MySQL server?

Comment: How many CPU cores do you have at Amazon?  I've seen much higher and systems still chugging along.  Like I said, the error log is probably a good place to start, both of mysqld and the system.  Did mysqld actually crash/restart or did it just affect your tables?

Comment: It's a t1.micro with just a single cpu core. It's burstable to go a bit faster than that, but only for a short while. Which looking at my own logs, it had been for some time (an hour or more). I just updated the post with my mysql log.

Comment: From the looks of it, those entries are only after mysqld crashed, not signifying the cause of the crash.

Comment: Probably oom-killer. t1.micro does not have much RAM.